# getting sender object in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am making a game using cocos2d. By using the following code,I have added an animation.How do I send the `CCSprite` reference?

```
if(sprite != monkey)
{
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(animate_sprite:) delay:0.1f];
}

-(void)animate_sprite:(ccTime) dt
{
    id s2 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:2.0 scaleY:2.0];
    id fun = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDone:)];
    [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:s2,fun,nil]];
}
```

How to get the sprite reference in `animate_sprite` method?

Comment: make sprite an ivar, or give it a tag and use getchildbytag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` this will do the same thing.

```
if(sprite != monkey)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(animate_sprite:) withObject:sprite afterDelay:0.1f];
}

-(void)animate_sprite:(CCSprite *)sprite
{

    id s2 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:2.0 scaleY:2.0];
    id fun = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteDone:)];
    [sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:s2,fun,nil]];
}
```

So just edit your method to use the sprite and not the ccTime object since you are not using it at all.

Comment: thanks for your reply.But how to get sprite object in animate_sprite method?

Comment: Its working while am calling from init method.But When I called from-(void) update: (ccTime) dt this method animation not working.From CCtime animation wont work?